# Using Chazelle's simplicity test to verify simple polygons intersection

Tags: computational-geometry

Is there a way to verify whether a non-empty intersection exists between two simple polygons (not necessarily convex) using the Chazelle's simplicity test ?

Comment: Perhaps connecting the two polygons together by a "bridge" to form one polygon might allow Chazelle's algorithm to answer the question.  But: Are you interested in this for theoretical purposes, or for pragmatic reasons?  If the latter, it would be far easier to use a plane-sweep algorithm than it would be to implement Chazelle's algorithm.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80798/detecting-polygon-self-intersection and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52733/equation-to-check-if-a-set-of-vertices-form-a-real-polygon

Answer (score 2):

Independent of Chazelle, a discussion of the case of intersecting convex polygons can be found at:

- [cs.mcgill.ca](http://www-cgrl.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Egodfried/teaching/cg-projects/97/Plante/CompGeomProject-EPlante/algorithm.html)
- [springer.com](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01898355)

Comment: Yes, although note that the convex-convex case is very special and will not help much for two simple polygons.