# Efficient algorithms for testing simplicity of a 2D polygon given its vertices?

Tags: algorithms, polygons, convex-geometry

I'm working on a project that requires me to test if a polygon is convex and I was able to write an algorithm that successfully tests for convexity for simple polygons but fails to provide the correct answers for some non-simple ones, like star-shaped ones.

For this reason I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to test for simplicity of a polynomial given its vertices, to run before testing for convexity. For now I was able to find [this](http://hera.ugr.es/doi/15026760.pdf) paper describing an algorithm for simplicity test but I'm failing to really understand how it should work. I tried an implementation based on this one but it doesn't work so apparently I misunderstood. Also it's not super efficient so I appreciate any other suggestion.

**EDIT**:

**My convexity test**

const nVertices: number = polygon.length;
let res: number = 0;
let isConvex: boolean = true;

```
        polygon.forEach( (thisVertex: Vertex, i: number) => {
            const thisV: Vertex = thisVertex;
            const nextV: Vertex = polygon[(i+1) % nVertices];
            const secondNextV: Vertex =  polygon[(i+2) % nVertices];
            const v: Vertex = [nextV[0] - thisV[0], nextV[1] - thisV[1]];

            if( i === 0 )
                res = secondNextV[0]*v[1] - secondNextV[1]*v[0] + v[0]*thisV[1] - v[1]*thisV[0];
            else {
                const newRes: number = secondNextV[0]*v[1] - secondNextV[1]*v[0] + v[0]*thisV[1] - v[1]*thisV[0];
                if ( (newRes > 0 && res < 0) || (newRes < 0 && res > 0) )
                    isConvex = false;
            }
        } )
```

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80798/detecting-polygon-self-intersection and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52733/equation-to-check-if-a-set-of-vertices-form-a-real-polygon

Answer (score 0):

I assume your polygon is drawn with respect to a fixed order of its vertices $v_0,…,v_{n-1}$, by which I mean that if you travel along the boundary you visit the vertices in the fixed order. **Edit** I also assume the polygon to be simple!

Now note that intuitively a polygon should be convex if and only if when traveling along the boundary all turns are made in the same direction. Hit me up, if you want a formal proof for this.

For this purpose we only need to know if we make a turn to the left or to the right. Given two vectors $v,w$ we can determine wether $w$ is to the left or to the right of $v$ by computing $\operatorname{sign}(v.x\cdot w.y - v.y\cdot w.x)$, positive meaning right and negative meaning left. The reason why this works is that the cross-product of three-dimensional vectors satisfies the right hand rule and for vectors in the x-y-plane only the third component will give nontrivial information, either pointing up or down.

Anyway we can use this to test for convexity. Just consider the following pseudo-code:

```
s = 0
for i=0 to n-1
    j = i+1 mod n
    k = i+1 mod n
    v = v_j - v_i
    w = v_k - v_i
    t = sign(v.xw.y - v.yw.x)
    if s = 0
        s = t
    if t != 0 and t != s
        return not convex
return convex
```

By using the for loop we go around the polygon. The vector $v$ is the next segment and the $w$ is the vertex which will follow the segment. We test whether it lies on the left or right of the segment and test whether it is the same for all segments.

Comment: @JonasLissen: does this work for self-intercepting polygons like star-shaped ones? Cause if my mind serves my convexity test implentation used that exact same principle but failed in the star "test".

Comment: I think it does, but I spontaneously cooked up this solution, so I might have overlooked some edge case. If you go around a star you make turns alternating to the left and to the right, so I don’t see why this algorithm should fail. I am unsure what happens if your vertices have random order.

Comment: I updated my question to include my convexity test code. The issue with the code above is that as you see here: https://github.com/NickTheFreak97/Pathfinder/issues/8 the star polygon does test as convex, which obviously it isn't. The vertices are ordered in the same sequence of the clicks, and changing the order of the vertices results in changing the polygon itself too since I modeled the polygon to be represented by the ordered sequence of its vertices.

Comment: The code should work for simple polygons, but does not work for self-intersecting polygons, like what one gets from drawing a 5-pointed star with 5 segments.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you, know I understand what was meant with self-intersecting. You are perfectly right, I did not consider this case (or rather tried to exclude it by my assumptions on the order of vertices, which maybe wasn’t stated clear and precise enough). I am not really sure how to define the „interior“ of this kind of polygon anyway.

Comment: @JonasLinssen Usually, the interior of this type of polygon is defined via parity.  The interior is the set of points where a path to infinity crosses an odd number of edges.