# Detecting polygon self intersection

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I'm looking for the algorithm that determines the fact that a polygon has self intersection or hasn't. I'm not needed in calculation of the intersection points coordinates or how many intersection points there are.

Comment: The naïve algorithm is to compare each pair of edges to see whether they overlap. Do you want an optimal algorithm or have any interesting constraints (e.g. polygon endpoints on lattice points)?

Comment: No special constraints. I only need a very fast algorithm for this task.

Comment: Posssible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52733/equation-to-check-if-a-set-of-vertices-form-a-real-polygon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is the obvious algorithm of comparing all pairs of edges, which is $O(n^2)$ but probably is ok for small polygons. There is the [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley-Ottmann_algorithm) sweep algorithm, which is  $O(n \log n)$ but is harder to implement and probably only needed if $n$ is large. I think there is a $O(n)$ algorithm by Chazelle, which is very likely to be impractical.

In any case, note that you can test whether two line segments intersect *without* finding the intersection point. It's a simple matter of comparing signs of a few determinants. See http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/91primitives/.

Comment: Is the Chazelle one [this one](http://akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f03/Artikler/12/Chazelle92.pdf)?

Comment: @LarsW, yes, that paper: An Optimal Algorithm for Intersecting Line Segments in the Plane, B. Chazelle, H. Edelsbrunner, Journal ACM 39 (1992), 1-54.

Answer (score 2):

The Shamos-Hoey algorithm is designed for the task of simply reporting whether a polygon has self-intersections or not.

There is an excellent writeup [in this blog](http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html#Shamos-Hoey-Algorithm) and there are many implementations available (include my own [in javascript](https://github.com/rowanwins/shamos-hoey) which also includes the original PDF of the paper).

Comment: I think the blog article is no longer available at that link, but [here's a version from archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217204036/http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html#Shamos-Hoey-Algorithm).